# How to find the standard atomic orbital energy data?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, orbitals, photoelectric-effect, data

I found a website that provides the $d$ orbital energy of atoms. The data were found using Photoelectron Spectroscopy, which measures the energy needed to ionize electrons from atoms in the gas phase.

But I can't find an authoritative data source. where could I find the standard data sources?

Here is the website: http://www.graylark.com/eve/orbital-energies-table.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principal standard reference for physicists data and formula is National Institute of Standards and Technology

[Nist.gov](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database)

Comment: I am struggling to extract the correct data. for example, I want to know the energy of the d orbital of Fe element. I tried to search the `Fe I` in the Atomic Spectra Database, so I thought I could use the energy difference between  `3d64s2` and `3d54s2`,  but there are many configurations for `3d64s2` and `3d54s2`. Which one should I choose to represent the two configurations?